# Working with document bookmarks in Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I frequently work on long Microsoft Word documents that have chapter headings, and I often set up bookmarks for those chapters. However, the only way to see a list of them is to open the "Go To" dialog box, click "Bookmark", and the list of bookmarks appears on a menu.

There's got to be a better way.

Word is quite customizable, even on the Mac; is there any way to make this friendlier? Maybe a toolbar button that shows all bookmarks in the active document? A keyboard shortcut that will open up a list of all document bookmarks? (The dialog for Insert > Bookmark... would do the job, but I can't locate the command in the "Customize Keyboard" dialog.)

I'd love to setup a toolbar or ribbon button that would automatically display all bookmarks in the active document, perhaps in a pop-up menu. Is there any way of doing this or something like it?